# How to create a socket.io server that can send and receive data to multiple computers and not just on the same computer.(in javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am pretty new to *node.js* and *socket.io* .   I know how to create localhost and send data to my local computer and receive data. One of the way can probably be:
`const app = require('express')()`
`const server = require('http').createServer(app)`
`const io = require('socket.io').listen(server)`
`server.listen(3000)`
But now, assume that I had deployed this project on the web, how can I be able to create a server that can send and receive data to **other computers** on the web. Does anyone know how I'm gonna be able to achieve this?  Pls be specific, because I am pretty new to programming.

Comment: You'll need a server somewhere to install this on.  Easiest thing to do is get a cheap VPS, such as over on DigitalOcean or similar.

Comment: .........................................

Comment: Not sure what you expect us to interpret from a bunch of dots...

Comment: ignore the dots

Comment: To Brad  --- Do you know any free VPS available out there?

Comment: You can also run your server from your home initially (at small scale).  You will just have to set up port forwarding from your router to your server.  If done properly, it can be safe.

Comment: I've seen some people saying that connecting to a DNS or Ip address rather than localhost can be the solution, is it possible?

Comment: You can run at home, set up port forwarding and then the outside computer can connect to your route's public IP address.  Or, you can use a dynamic DNS service to set up a domain name for your public IP address.  This wouldn't be a production configuration, but could be a good way to do your development, test things out and decide if you want to pay for a hosting service.

Comment: jdriend00-- Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @ycl310 Heroku is a free hosting service for node js, you get 5 free node js apps. I found it really helpful for hosting my projects and you can upload your code with ease using git, there are also hundreds of tutorials on how to upload and run your node app on their servers.